# XSLT - String split

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

My objective is analyze the text() node of a given XML document and identify the upper case words and if that word length > 3 add `'*'` character in between 3,4 characters (6,7 and 9,10.....)

example,

input XML :

```
<chap>
    <para>The BEGINNING of this COLUMN shows the INPUT and output</para>
</chap>
```

desired output:

```
<chap>
    <para>The BEG*INN*ING of this COL*UMN shows the INP*UT and output</para>
</chap>
```

I've written following xsl to do this task,

```
<xsl:template match="para">
        <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="[(A-Z)]">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:variable name="reg" select="string(regex-group(0))"/>
                    <xsl:call-template name="add-star">
                        <xsl:with-param name="str" select="$reg"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:matching-substring>

            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="add-star">
        <xsl:param name="str" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:if test="string-length($str)>3">
            <xsl:call-template name="add-star">
                <xsl:with-param name="str" select="substring($str,4,200)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:sequence select="string-join(substring($str,1,3),'*')"/>
    </xsl:template>
```

but it does not work as expected.since there is no variables like oop languages I'm struggling to to this task in XSLT, could anyone suggest me how can I modify my code to do this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
<xsl:template match="para">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="([A-Z]+)(\s|$)">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:variable name="sub" as="xs:string*">
                    <xsl:for-each select="0 to (string-length(regex-group(1)) - 1) idiv 3">
                        <xsl:sequence select="substring(regex-group(1), (. ) * 3 + 1, 3)" />
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:value-of select="string-join($sub, '*')"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Test: http://xsltransform.net/jyRYYiN

Answer (score 1):

And here is another exslt-enabled xslt-1.0 solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
                xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
                xmlns:func="http://exslt.org/functions"
                xmlns:my="http://my.org/xsl"
                extension-element-prefixes="fn str func">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes"/>

    <func:function name="my:to-upper">
        <xsl:param name="str" select="''"/>

        <func:result select="translate($str, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')"/>
    </func:function>

    <func:function name="my:is-upper">
        <xsl:param name="str" select="''"/>

        <func:result select="my:to-upper($str) = $str"/>
    </func:function>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="./@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="./node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:if test="string-length(normalize-space(.)) > 0">
            <xsl:for-each select="str:tokenize(., ' ')">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="my:is-upper(.)">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="string-length(.) > 3">
                                <xsl:for-each select="str:tokenize(., '')">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>

                                    <xsl:if test="0 = position() mod 3 and not(position() = last())">
                                        <xsl:text>*</xsl:text>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </xsl:when>

                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:when>

                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>

                <xsl:if test="not(position() = last())">
                    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Online [Demo](http://xsltransform.net/pPzifpS)